# nslookup working with www.domain.com but not with domain.com

Tags: networking, dns

Something very curious happened while I was doing nslookup in a website. For example, if I do this with **github.com** and **www.github.com** I get the following

```
C:\Users\Hyper>nslookup github.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.1.1

Non-authoritative answer:
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Name:    github.com
Address:  140.82.113.4
```

```
C:\Users\Hyper>nslookup www.github.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.1.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    github.com
Address:  140.82.114.3
Aliases:  www.github.com
```

Both give me an IP address. But look at what happens with this webpage **banesco.com**

```
C:\Users\Hyper>nslookup www.banesco.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.1.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    banesco-produccion.siscotel.io
Addresses:  52.0.178.199
          3.230.30.180
          3.230.106.149
Aliases:  www.banesco.com
```

```
C:\Users\Hyper>nslookup banesco.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.1.1

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Request to UnKnown timed-out
```

Why does it work with **www.banesco.com** but not with **banesco.com**?

Comment: I hope you understand that `140.82.113.4` and `140.82.114.3` are not actually identical.  However, this has to do with the way the server for the domain in question is configured, and it's being reported to your nameserver provider.

Comment: because the DNS for github has an entry for both while the DNS for banesco doesnt have an entry for both. if you have a linux box or a cygwin try with `dig` and you will see in the reply the ANSWER section.

Comment: @Ramhound sorry i misread the IP address

Comment: @Zina I tried `dig banesco.com` in Ubuntu 16, I get a timeout as well. Is there a reason for not configuring both entries? (for www.domain.com and domain.com)

Comment: @FlowMafia - I would be shocked, if it's anything but personal preference of the individual, who configured the server.

Comment: no reason, depends what you want to achieve. so the admin decided not to add them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `banesco.com` zone is delegated to four nameservers:

- ns1.globalcrossing.net.ve
- ns2.globalcrossing.net.ve
- dns.banesco.com
- dns1.banesco.com

When you make a query for this domain or any of its subdomains (and if there's no cached response yet), the query eventually gets forwarded to one of those servers – chosen basically at random.

Two of those nameservers (the ones provided by GlobalCrossing.net.ve) **are currently broken** – they only respond with a "Server failure" error code. If your query ended up being routed to them, it'll either return the same error code or outright time out.

Comment: not true, as when you do a `dig @<any of the 4 DNS nameservers> banesco.com` - ALL return NOERROR, ANSWER:0, AUTHORITY:1 - which indicates that there is no record to return.

Comment: How did you know the nameservers?

Comment: Any website designed to look up the nameserver of a domain would provide that information.  (I.e whois.net for example).  In fact I would be shocked if that wasn’t the website the author of this answer used.

Comment: I used `dnstrace -s . banesco.com` which directly queries the NS records as they currently are. (It has the advantage of showing delegations at any level, not only immediately under a TLD, among other reasons.)